# Application's Toolbar is not collapsing when Scrolling RecyclerView inside fragments

Tags: java, android

Application's Toolbar is not collapsing. Here is my `activity_main` xml file, how

to collapse the application toolbar. I tried implementing with the bellow code but my code doesn't even collapse and showing something else. If i remove the 
`android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout` tag then I can see my original layout like

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83LjE.png) is the view without implementation of CollapsingToolBar.

More about the design is, I have 9 tabs with 9 fragments implemented for each tab with `RecyclerView` in it. While scrolling the `recyclerview` upwards the toolbar is not collapsing after implementation of `CollapsingToolBa`r in the `activity_main.xml` file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#f90404"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"/>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_line">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="5dp">

        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mensaje_vp_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:clickable="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemTextColor="#780d0d"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items"
            />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/cartoon"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#ffe5e5"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingTop="10dp">
         <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />
         <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />
         <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />
      </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

> More [Reference](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example_7.html)

Comment: nothing worked for me.. I tried with the two given help but it looks like all the views are overlapping with each other

Comment: i min after making the toolbar collapse the UI should be as same as my given one.

Comment: @Reyansh check my reference code as well output for me it worked fine if you found it useful please upvote me

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the layout below `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_line">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            android:background="#f90404"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="5dp">

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mensaje_vp_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:clickable="true"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemTextColor="#780d0d"
        app:menu="@menu/sample_actions"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```